# How to include IF condition inside a HTML Table

Tags: php, html

I need to use IF condition to check whether a PHP variable is equal to some value or not.
Here is my try..

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
    $qDate .= '<td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
    $qStatus .= '<td style="text-align:center">'.$row['Status'].'</td>';
}
```

Then I need to include a html table into a phpvariable as below.

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
$messagenew.= '
    <table style="top: 15px; left:10px; " border=1>

        <tbody>
            <caption style="color: rgb(241, 239, 243);background: rgb(1, 32, 65); ">Status</caption>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center"><b>Date</td>'.$qDate .'
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <?php if($qStatus=="Not Received"){?>
                  <td style="text-align:center;background-color: red;"><b>Status</td>'.$qStatus_SEQ .'
                <?php}?>
                <?php else{ ?>
                   <td style="text-align:center;background-color: Green;"><b>Status</td>'.$qStatus_SEQ .'
                <?php } ?>                  
                
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
';

    
}
else{
    $messagenew.= 'Data is not Available';
    
}
```

I have enclosed php code with tags. But still I am not getting the required output. Rather than highlighting the value I can see my Header(Status) have highlighted.And the table were also messed up. Can someone help me on this.

Update:messagenew variable can be seen when mail generated.Mail generating code not attached here.

Comment: if only ** if statement ** you may use ?? operator 
otherwise you may use the condition and concat your table with it e.g. 

$table = "<table> "; 
if(condition){
   $table .= "<tr> <td> lorem ipsum </td></tr>";
}
else{
$table .= "<tr> <td> my heading</td></tr>";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned Your Headers are only changing, You better to assign the rule when you are fetching data. Try below..

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
    $qDate .= '<td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['Date'].'</td>';
    if($row['Status']=='Not Received') {
        $qStatus .= '<td style="text-align:center;background-color: red;">'.$row['Status'].'</td>';
     }
    else{
   $qStatus .= '<td style="text-align:center;background-color: green;">'.$row['Status'].'</td>';
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use variable in if to get required result

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $messagenew.= '
        <table style="top: 15px; left:10px; " border=1>
            <tbody>
                <caption style="color: rgb(241, 239, 243);background: rgb(1, 32, 65); ">Status</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><b>Date</td>'.$qDate .'
                </tr>
    
                <tr>';
                    if($qStatus=="Not Received"){
                      $messagenew.= '<td style="text-align:center;background-color: red;"><b>Status</td>'.$qStatus_SEQ;
                    }else{
                        $messagenew.= '<td style="text-align:center;background-color: Green;"><b>Status</td>'.$qStatus_SEQ;
                   }                 
                    
                $messagenew.= '</tr>
    
            </tbody>
        </table>';
    
        
    }
    else{
        $messagenew.= 'Data is not Available';
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the Shorthand If / Else conditional method

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $messagenew.= '
        <table style="top: 15px; left:10px; " border=1>
    
            <tbody>
                <caption style="color: rgb(241, 239, 243);background: rgb(1, 32, 65); ">Status</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><b>Date</td>'.$qDate .'
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;background-color: '.($qStatus=="Not Received") ? 'red' : 'Green'.';"><b>Status</td>'.$qStatus_SEQ .'                    
                </tr>
    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    ';
    
        
    }
    else{
        $messagenew.= 'Data is not Available';
        
    }
```

Comment: This prints just "Red" in my message varible.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use curly brackets and double quotes?

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $condition = if ($qStatus == "Not Received") ? "<td style='text-align:center;background-color: red;'><b>Status</td>{$qStatus_SEQ}" : "<td style='text-align:center;background-color: Green;'><b>Status</td>{$qStatus_SEQ}";
    $messagenew.= "
        <table style='top: 15px; left:10px;' border=1>
            <tbody>
                <caption style='color: rgb(241, 239, 243);background: rgb(1, 32, 65);'>Status</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align:center'><b>Date</td>{$qDate}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {$condition}                
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    ";
}
else
{
    $messagenew.= 'Data is not Available';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if only **if statement**  is needed you may use ?? operator
otherwise you may use the condition and concat your table variable
***e.g.***

```
$table = "<table> "; 
if(condition){
   $table .= "<tr> <td> lorem ipsum </td></tr>";
}
else{
$table .= "<tr> <td> my heading</td></tr>";
}
```